# Firebase Security rules, public readable on specific node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a database with the following fields:

```
users
vacancy
user application
user data
```

now vacancy should be readable by all user and other nodes must be read authenticated user,

my Firebase database rule

```
  {
  "rules": {

    "Vacancy":{
      "$uid":{
         ".read": "true",
      },
        ".read": "auth != null",

    ".write": "auth != null",
    }
  }
}
```

but this not work for me please help me

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that makes the queries that aren't working the way you expect.  Rules are meaningless without being paired up with code.  Also, you tagged this google-cloud-functions - are you actually using Cloud Functions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure the problem is because `".read": "auth != null",` is above the rules for vacancy. Try moving it below that block. The rules work in sequential order and any subordinate rules are ignored.

**Update**

You changed your original rules in this post. Don't do that, show the new version as well.

What I mean you to try is:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Vacancy":{
    ".read": "true",
    },
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
  }
}
```

For more insight check this site : https://www.fullstackfirebase.com/realtime-database/security-rules

Comment: Glad it works...test it fully though, I have been wrong with rules before :-)